# Import a textfile list into a python list

Tags: python, list

I have a .txt textfile with a list formatted like 
`[' ok ', ' test ', ' help ']`
How can I read/import this textfile list into a python list?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval):

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as file:
    result = eval(file.read())
```

**However**, `eval()` is usually not recommended, since it will evaluate any string you feed to it. That includes arbitrary code a malicious user might have put in the file. To avoid that, you should use [`literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) instead:

```
from ast import literal_eval

with open("file.txt", "r") as file:
    result = literal_eval(file.read())
```

Unlike the regular `eval()` function, `literal_eval()` only evaluates strings that convert to basic python types (this includes lists and dictionaries, which  are what this is most commonly used for).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use literal_eval

```
from ast import literal_eval
with open("example.txt","r") as stuff:
    answer= literal_eval(stuff.read())
```